# How to properly print a downward left star triangle using While?

Tags: javascript

Currently, here's my code and currently stock wit hthis

```
let star = "*";
let length = 0;
let height = 4;

while(length < 5){
 
 while(height > length){
   process.stdout.write(star);
   height--;
 }
console.log(star);
length++;
}
```

and its output currently is:

```
* * * * *
*
*
*
*
```

the expected output is:

```
* * * * *
  * * * *
    * * *
      * * 
        *
```

Comment: You are not accounting for spaces. You need to add spaces as well

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is more suitable the 'for' statement than the 'while' statement. Also, as that triangle has the same sides (height = width), then you can use only one variable (i called 'size'). You can create the line just by adding the characters, including the space, and printing it when completed:

```
let size = 5;

for (let row = 0; row < size; row++) { 
  let line = ''
  for (let col = 0; col < size; col++) {
    line += (col < row) ? ' ' : '*'
  }
  console.log(line)
}
```